# Products are not visible in front end in magento 2.2 and how to make it to visible in front end?

Tags: php, magento2.2

I have installed Magento 2.2 and have created new products in admin end.
Those products are saved in DB, but it is failed to display in the store front.
If I created configurable product, after saving  it automatically changed to virtual product.
Please solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify weight for associated products of configurable products. This will convert virtual products to simple products.

Also check after reindexing and cache clean. Note that you set IN STOCK for main configurable product and IN STOCK as well as QTY greater than zero for all associated products.

Answer (score 3):

Check following things

- Is Product "In Stock " ?
- Is a simple product associated to configurable product ? also simple product are "In Stock " ?
- Reindexed `(php bin/magento indexer:reindex)`
- Make sure visibility set to "Catalog Search" 
  And Last thing product is assigned to proper store or website.

Just check this hope this helps.

Thanks.